Practical applicability of the Hopf's formula for 2nd group homology
For a given group $G$ and its free presentation $R \hookrightarrow F \twoheadrightarrow G$, the Hopf's formula states that $H_2(G) \cong \frac{R \cap [F,F]}{[F,R]}$.
Is that formula practically applicable for computing group homologies? If so, in what contexts is it commonly used in computations, and are there any limitations or challenges to its practical application?
To illustrate the question, I can ask about the next example: in the case when $G$ is equal to Klein four-group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, we know that $H_2(G) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ due to Künneth formula. But can we obtain that result using Hopf's formula and commutator identities only?
The question is important for me since I see the connection between the theory of syzygies and Hopf's formula. I know basic facts that second homology is about relations among relations (see CLAIR MILLER, THE SECOND HOMOLOGY GROUP OF A GROUP; RELATIONS AMONG COMMUTATORS), but I want to make this connection precise and see it in terms of concrete groups.

For finite groups with finite presentation, this formula will give you the second homology, since in that case the subgroup $R\cap[F,F]/[F,R]$ is exactly the torsion subgroup of $R/[F,R]$, a finitely generated Abelian group. So all of this is computable (in simple cases by hand). I'd encourage you to try it for the Klein group!

@SteveD, thank you a lot! Because of your comment, I remembered that there is a trick that helps to compute that group. I remember that the trick is connected with abelianization, but can't figure out the details.
But, I have the next idea. Using commutator identities,one may obtain $[x^2,y] = [x,y]^x \cdot [x, y] = [x, y] \cdot [[x,y],x] \cdot [x,y]$. This is the another form of the generator of $[R, F]$. Now, since $[F,[F,F]] \subset [R,F]$, we could apply 3rd isomorphism theorem.

In our case, we get that $H_2(G) \cong \frac{R \cap [F,F] / [F,[F,F]] } {[R,F] / [F,[F,F]]}$. The identity turns into $[x,y]^2$, and that gives the torsion element in second homology group.
Am I correct?
